# Разработал я сервер на node js. Что дальше

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-сервер

Привет народ.
Вот видимо я зашел в тупик. Сервер написан, сайт работает но только на localhost. Как, как мне сделать что бы я мог обращаться к этому серверу через интернет, с других компов? 
Сервер запущен на ноутбуке.
Киньте ссылки, статьи, дайте совет пожалуйста, не знаю куда дальше двигаться.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Каким образом компьютер подключен к интернету?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться информацией отсюда :

https://gun.io/blog/tutorial-deploy-node-js-server-with-example/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: Мне кажется это не тот случай, когда можно выделить "самое главное", так как в вопросе не указана операционная система, веб-сервер. Так же в вопросе просьба дать совет\ссылку на статьи, что собственно я и сделал :)

Comment: @Bezarius Если в вопросе не указано самое главное - надо проголосовать за закрытие с соответствующей причиной и попросить автора добавить больше деталей. Отвечать двумя ссылками вникуда (а что сразу убунту-то, вдруг у него винда?) - не стоит.